# '403 Forbidden error' when trying to access images on a Wordpress install

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I have a dedicated server. I have installed wordpress in a subdirectory on it and uploaded some images via the 'media' option in the dashboard. But I am unable to access images directly (hotlinks) in the browser, however, I can see the images in the file manager (FTP) under /wp-content/uploads folder.

It is a fresh install with no plugins and only the default theme. I haven't done anything other than upload a few images via the media option. Please note that the error shows even when I click the 'library' option under the 'media' option in the dashboard.

I even tried creating a .user.ini file in both the directories with the exact same code as of php.ini as shown below, but that didn't help either. The hosting provider says they don't provide support for dedicated servers. What do I do now?

Here is the root directory .htaccess

```
    <FilesMatch "\.(jpg|png|gif|js|css|ico)$">
            <IfModule mod_headers.c>
                    Header set ETag ""
                    Header set Cache-Control "max-age=2592000"
                    Header set Expires "01 Jan 2112 00:00:00 GMT"
            </IfModule>
    </FilesMatch>
    <IfModule mod_expires.c>
            ExpiresByType text/css "access plus 1 month"
            ExpiresByType text/javascript "access plus 1 month"
            ExpiresByType application/x-javascript "access plus 1 month"
            ExpiresByType image/gif "access plus 1 month"
            ExpiresByType image/jpg "access plus 1 month"
            ExpiresByType image/png "access plus 1 month"
    </IfModule>
    <FilesMatch "\.(jpg|png|gif|js|css|ico)$">
            <IfModule mod_headers.c>
                    Header set ETag ""
                    Header set Cache-Control "max-age=2592000"
                    Header set Expires "01 Jan 2112 00:00:00 GMT"
            </IfModule>
    </FilesMatch>
    <IfModule mod_expires.c>
            ExpiresByType text/css "access plus 1 month"
            ExpiresByType text/javascript "access plus 1 month"
            ExpiresByType application/x-javascript "access plus 1 month"
            ExpiresByType image/gif "access plus 1 month"
            ExpiresByType image/jpg "access plus 1 month"
            ExpiresByType image/png "access plus 1 month"
    </IfModule>
    # BEGIN SUGARCRM RESTRICTIONS
    RedirectMatch 403 (?i).*\.log$
    RedirectMatch 403 (?i)/+not_imported_.*\.txt
    RedirectMatch 403 (?i)/+(soap|cache|xtemplate|data|examples|include|log4php|metadata|modules)/+.*\.(php|tpl)
    RedirectMatch 403 (?i)/+emailmandelivery\.php
    RedirectMatch 403 (?i)/+upload
    RedirectMatch 403 (?i)/+custom/+blowfish
    RedirectMatch 403 (?i)/+cache/+diagnostic
    RedirectMatch 403 (?i)/+files\.md5$
    # END SUGARCRM RESTRICTIONS
    <FilesMatch "\.(jpg|png|gif|js|css|ico)$">
            <IfModule mod_headers.c>
                    Header set ETag ""
                    Header set Cache-Control "max-age=2592000"
                    Header set Expires "01 Jan 2112 00:00:00 GMT"
            </IfModule>
    </FilesMatch>
    <IfModule mod_expires.c>
            ExpiresByType text/css "access plus 1 month"
            ExpiresByType text/javascript "access plus 1 month"
            ExpiresByType application/x-javascript "access plus 1 month"
            ExpiresByType image/gif "access plus 1 month"
            ExpiresByType image/jpg "access plus 1 month"
            ExpiresByType image/png "access plus 1 month"
    </IfModule>
```

Here is the Wordpress directory .htaccess

```
    # BEGIN WordPress
    <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /laksh/3/wordpress/
    RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule . /laksh/3/wordpress/index.php [L]
    </IfModule>

    # END WordPress
```

Here is the php.ini code in both the directories:

```
    file_uploads = On
    upload_max_filesize = 100M
    post_max_size = 100M
```

The uploaded images won't even display in pages or posts.

Comment: So what does your http servers error log file reveal what the issue is?

Comment: @arkascha are you referring to the file name 'error_log' in my server's root directory? That file shows an internal error 500 when I view it.
And there is another named 'error_log_bk', that one only shows errors between 29 nov and 30 nov 2018.

Comment: The apache http server writes two log files, access and error log file. Their location is a configuration thing, you want to check that setting. In general: you _can not_ develop inside a web environment without monitoring your error log file. That would be like flying around in a narrow cave - with your eyes blindfolded. Sure, possible, but it makes no sense.

Comment: Maybe you want to post that error you see. HTTP status 500 only says that there is an internal error, that is the report for the client, as visible in the browser, it does _not_ contain the actual error cause. The _real_ error log file contains much more valuable information: the specific cause that lead to the http status 500. That is what you are interested in.

Comment: Are you referring  to the 500 error that shows when I try to open the error_log file?

Comment: Once more: an http status 500 is not really helpful since it contains no internal details about what the actual issue is. It is intended as an information for the requesting client who should not receive information about internal details. So either that file is _not_ the actual apache error log file (it might be the access log file, that also shows the resulting http status). Or you need to find the location of the _real_ error log file.

Comment: About that error log file your http server writes: I explained to you what file I refer to and how it's location is configured. Did you find out that location? So what does _that_ file contain? And if you did not, then _why_ not?

Answer (score 1):

Worth checking if

```
RedirectMatch 403 (?i)/+upload
```

is the cause of your images not being displayed, the wordpress path for uploaded images, containers the string `upload`